# How is the same filename cascading named in visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, solution-explorer

This seem to only occur in asp.net project with wwwroot folder.

How can I configure that behavior?

I do not want that .html appear as parent, buth .js and js.map together are fine.

[image]

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: I use VS 2015 Update 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670209/typescript-html-js-file-nesting-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @vinjenzo Thanks for the link, but that does not explain why my files outside the scripts/typescript folder are nested. I move them there with gulp tasks. They are not created/added manually under wwwroot.

Comment: Firstly tell how did you create adminstation.html as parent and js & jsmap files as its childrens?

Comment: the administration.html was created there manually. The .js and .map were copied over there from the TypeScript scripts source folder.

Comment: Isn't it just a feature? There are more people with this issue: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10924407-option-to-disable-file-nesting-in-asp-net-5-mvc

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to rename the nested files. They are only nested if they have the exact same name before the dot. Just put an underscore before the name or another prefix you like.

**Remember: You need to rename them outside of Visual Studio.**

Normally JS and CSS files are stored in separate folders. That would also solve your problem. I guess this is the better way to do it.

fyi: For other project types, there is a Visual Studio Extension, which modifies the nested state. Maybe this will be updated, once Asp.Net Core is finally released.

[File Nesting Extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c)

Thre is also an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/347)